# Is a new gae app permission for xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com safe?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, permissions, google-cloud-platform

I added a [google identity API](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/) in my gcloud panel last couple of days today I notice a new permission in my admin console for the gae project.

[image]

I*m in good faith assuming the account `...xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com` is good and a service account for real since I added a gcloud identity service or something else that is not a security or a privacy issue. Can you confirm or let me know about the account type that I didn't add myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@developer.gserviceaccount.com are Google APIs service accounts. Project editor permissions are granted automatically upon creation and are listed under https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project/permissions. project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com are App Engine service accounts added automatically upon project creation.